# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name start_value was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error, when the spring-boot application is starting up.

> [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl] - Could
> not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name start_value was not
> found in this ResultSet.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
Postgres DB version = 8.4
```

Primary key generation in JPA entity

```
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)  
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false ,columnDefinition = "serial")  
private Integer id;
```

The sequence is already created on the DB side, and the sequence is configured as the default value to ID column in the table.

I have used different Postgres dialects and am still getting the same problem.
I want to know whether it is a fatal error for the application, and what is the fix for this error?

Comment: You are probably using a JDBC driver that doesn't work with your outdated and unsupported Postgres version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your quick reply.I ll check it

Comment: @hazzy1986 What is your db sequence name? Could you please also show ddl of your table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name problem is solved, once I installed the postgres version 12. Thank you