# Cannot load ApplicationContext due to Hibernate selecting a non-existent column from information_schema.sequences

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

## Problem

I get `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name start_with was not found in this ResultSet.` when trying to run `applicationContext.refresh();` after I load my configuration.

##### **EDIT**: I can replicate this error on any Postgres instance by simply creating a sequence. I think this is an error with Hibernate.

This occurs when Hibernate runs the following query:

```sql
select * from information_schema.sequences
```

It expects the column `start_with` to be present in the `ResultSet`.

The exception is being raised specifically in `SequenceInformationExtractorHSQLDBDatabaseImpl#sequenceStartValueColumn`:

```java
    package org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal;

    /**
    * @author Vlad Mihalcea
    */
    public class SequenceInformationExtractorHSQLDBDatabaseImpl extends SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl {
        /**
        * Singleton access
        */
        public static final SequenceInformationExtractorHSQLDBDatabaseImpl INSTANCE = new SequenceInformationExtractorHSQLDBDatabaseImpl();

        @Override
        protected String sequenceStartValueColumn() {
            return "start_with";
        }
    }
```

## What I've Tried

- I found a [similar problem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945612/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-the-column-name-start-value-was-not-found-in). They needed to update Postgres, so I downloaded the Docker images for Postgres 13, 11, and 8. *I am able to load Spring and persist entities in all of these versions*.
- I also tried downgrading my `org.postgresql` version (to 42.2.02) since I think my database might be a bit old. The same error occurred with my main database, but not with my Docker containers.
- My database is using a schema.  I tried setting the default schema to its schema in the Hibernate config. *This didn't do anything*.
- I also made my Docker containers use a schema like in my main database. Nothing changed.
- Running the query (`select * from information_schema.sequences`) that is causing the problem, I can see that my Docker containers return identical results to what my database returns.
- I compared the calls stacks between running against Docker and my database. The code that is causing the exception *is not even run when I'm running against Docker*.

## Questions

- Why is `SequenceInformationExtractorHSQLDBDatabaseImpl#sequenceStartValueColumn` even being called?  As I mentioned, this is not called when I run against my Docker containers.
- Why is it searching for a non-existent column?
- Is there something wrong with my configuration?

I'm not really sure where else to look on this one.

## Details

**PostgreSQL version**:

`PostgreSQL 11.10 (Ubuntu 11.10-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit`

**POM**:

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.23</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Configuration**:

```java
package main.java.configuration;

import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://myhost:5432/db");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @PersistenceContext
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("main.java.dbentities");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("project");

        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    private static Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "myschema");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

**Application code**:

```java
class HibernateUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        
        applicationContext.register(HibernateConfiguration.class);
        applicationContext.refresh();
        applicationContext.close();
    }

}
```

**Full stack trace**:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper The column name start_with was not found in this ResultSet.
ERROR LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: ifiweekly] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in main.java.configuration.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ifiweekly] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at main.java.HibernateUtil.main(Main.java:254)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ifiweekly] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name start_with was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2589)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2485)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:181)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hibernate tries to choose a dialect that fits to the database version in use. I still couldn't figure out from your text which database version does not work for you. Once you write that with PostgreSQL 13, 11 and 8 you were unable to reproduce this and in the next section you write that this problem occurs with 11.

This might be a bug in one of the older PostgreSQL dialects of Hibernate, so if you could clearly write which version produces this error and which dialect is in use (should be reported on startup), you could create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with the exception details and maybe some more information like the actual columns of the table in the respective PostgreSQL version.

Comment: It occurs with all versions that I have tested.  As long as there is any sequence defined in the database, Hibernate tries to load that sequence.  But the columns that Hibernate expects from the sequence do not match the actual columns that Postgres uses. I was unable to create a Jira account (will try again), but pushed a fix here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/4180

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this ASAP.